# Access to service IP from the pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod with `mysql` and service to provide access from outside. So I can connect to my database at `192.168.1.29:3306` from the other machine.

But how I can connect from the other pod in the same cluster (same node)?

That is my service description:

```
Name:                     etl-mysql
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=etl-mysql
Annotations:              field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints=[{"addresses":["192.168.1.20"],"port":31211,"protocol":"TCP","serviceName":"default:etl-mysql","allNodes":true}]
                          kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"run":"etl-mysql"},"name":"etl-mysql","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"extern...
Selector:                 run=etl-mysql
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.43.44.58
External IPs:             192.168.1.29
Port:                     etl-mysql-port  3306/TCP
TargetPort:               3306/TCP
NodePort:                 etl-mysql-port  31211/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.1.87:3306
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes has a built in DNS, that registers services automatically resulting in simple to use DNS address like this: http://{servicename}.{namespace}:{servicePort}

If you are in the same namespace you can omit the namespace part and if your service listens on port 80 that part can be omitted as well.

If you need further informations the following documentation will help you: [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

Comment: So i need use this url http://etl-mysql:3306 in my case (both pods are in default namespace). Right? It doesn't work for my

Comment: Is the Pod running in the same namespace? If yes you should check if cluster dns is working. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

Comment: Yes, both pods is running in default namespace. By trying to test DNS i have an error after run:
kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default =>      
Server:  10.43.0.10
Address: 10.43.0.10:53

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN

*** Can't find kubernetes.default: No answer

Server:  10.43.0.10
Address: 10.43.0.10:53

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN

*** Can't find kubernetes.default: No answer

Comment: That means your Cluster DNS is broken. After you fix it the pods will find each other. Considering that services are important for things like load balancing, updates and many more you should fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately I find no errors in logs. It will be hard work to find the error((